# Angular 7. How can I import this shared module?

Tags: angular, angular-module

I have a module called `RequestModule`. I'm trying to use one of it's components `RequestComponent` and its `Services` inside of another component called `HomeComponent`

I thought I could just use the `Request component` in my `home.component.html` by using the selector like so

`Home.Component.Html
...
<request></request>
...`

 but I was wrong. I'm getting this error.

> : 'request' is not a known element:
>   1. If 'request' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.

How can I use this module in my home component?

Here is my RequestModule

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatCardModule, MatSidenavModule, MatGridListModule, MatIconModule, MatInputModule, MatTooltipModule, MatSelectModule, MatListModule, MatButtonModule, MatTabsModule, MatSnackBar, MatSnackBarModule } from '@angular/material';
import { RequestComponent } from './request.component';
import { RequestDetailsComponent } from './request-details.component';
import { RequestRoutingModule } from './request.routing';
import { DynamicFormComponent } from '../questionnaire/dynamic-form.component';
import { DynamicFormGroupComponent } from '../questionnaire/dynamic-form-group.component';
import { DynamicFormQuestionComponent } from '../questionnaire/dynamic-form-question.component';
import { CheckoutComponent } from './checkout.component';
import { SharedModule } from '../shared/shared.module';
import { ProductDetailsComponent } from './product-details.component';
import { CarouselComponent } from '../components/carousel/carousel.component';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { OwlDateTimeModule } from 'ng-pick-datetime';
import { OwlNativeDateTimeModule } from 'ng-pick-datetime';
import { OWL_DATE_TIME_LOCALE } from 'ng-pick-datetime';
import { OWL_DATE_TIME_FORMATS } from 'ng-pick-datetime';
import { RequestService } from './request.service';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    SharedModule,
    RequestRoutingModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatGridListModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatTooltipModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatListModule,
    NgbModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatTabsModule,
    MatSnackBarModule,
    OwlDateTimeModule,
    OwlNativeDateTimeModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    RequestComponent,
    RequestDetailsComponent,
    DynamicFormComponent,
    DynamicFormGroupComponent,
    DynamicFormQuestionComponent,
    CheckoutComponent,
    ProductDetailsComponent,
    CarouselComponent
  ],
  providers: [
      {provide: OWL_DATE_TIME_LOCALE, useValue: 'en-US'},
      RequestService
  ]
})
export class RequestModule { }
```

The `HomeComopnent` is Declared in the `template-routing.module.ts`

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
...
import { HomeComponent } from '../components/home/home.component';
...

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: TemplateComponent, children: [
    { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'home' },
    { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent},
     ...
    { path: 'request', canActivate: [AuthGuard], loadChildren: 'app/request/request.module#RequestModule' }
  ] }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class TemplateRoutingModule {}
```

This Module looks like it's already including the path to the RequestModule.

The `Template-routing.module` is used in my `template.module.ts`

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { TemplateComponent } from './template.component';
import { TemplateRoutingModule } from './template-routing.module';
import { RegionService } from '../region/region.service';
import { TeamModule } from '../team/team.module';
import { WorkModule } from '../work/work.module';
import { GraphicsModule } from '../graphics/graphics.module';
import { DashboardModule } from '../dashboard/dashboard.module';
import { SharedModule } from '../shared/shared.module';
import { LoginModule } from '../login/login.module';
import { MatInputModule, MatToolbarModule, MatIconModule, MatTooltipModule, MatButtonModule, MatSidenavModule } from '@angular/material';
import { HomeComponent } from '../components/home/home.component';
import { TemplateMenuComponent } from './template-menu/template-menu.component';
import { TemplateMenuItemComponent } from './template-menu-item/template-menu-item.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    SharedModule,
    TemplateRoutingModule,
    TeamModule,
    WorkModule,
    GraphicsModule,
    DashboardModule,
    LoginModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatTooltipModule,
    MatButtonModule
  ],
  declarations: [ TemplateComponent, HomeComponent, TemplateMenuComponent, TemplateMenuItemComponent ],
  providers: [ RegionService ]
})
export class TemplateModule {}
```

This `TemplateModule` Trickles up to my `AppRoutingModule` which finally trickles up to the `AppModule` where everything is bootstrapped.

How can I use the `Request` Component inside of my `HomeComopnent`?

[I've checked out this https://angular.io/guide/sharing-ngmodules](http://If%20more%20info%20is%20needed%20please%20let%20me%20know%20so%20I%20can%20edit%20this%20question.)

It looks like I did something wrong and I can't tell what it is.

If more info is needed please let me know so I can edit this question.

Comment: The problem may be due to the fact that you are trying to use a component that is in a module you are lazy loading. The home component won't know about the request component until something has loaded the module it's in.

Comment: @R.Richards I've tried removing the lazy loading and adding `Component: RequestComponent` and importing it, but that doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your shared `RequestModule` module needs to `export` all the services and components which it want to make available to any other module that imports it.

So your `RequestModule` would need to look like:

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [
     // Stuff here
  ],
  declarations: [
    RequestComponent,
    // Other components, etc
  ],
  exports: [
    RequestComponent //<-- Component now available to modules which import this one
  ]
  providers: [
     // Stuff here
  ]
})
export class RequestModule { }
```

From the Angular docs on exports

> **exports**: The set of components, directives, and pipes declared in this NgModule that can be used in the template of any component that is part of an NgModule that imports this NgModule. Exported declarations are the module's public API.
>   https://angular.io/api/core/NgModule

**Edit:**
Based on your comment, you're lazy loading the module in the routing. This isn't the same as adding it as an `import` reference to the module. A lazy loaded module works in semi-isolated state (it gets its own Dependency Injection container for example).

If you need a component to be used in the way you are, your `TemplateModule` (which has the `HomeComponent`) needs to `import` the `RequestModule`.

It may be worth reviewing why this component is needed in the `HomeComponent`. Maybe it should be a shared module?

Comment: Sorry but that doesn't fix the issue. I still get the same error. Maybe I'm missing something else.

Comment: Ah ok, missed the fact that it was lazy loading based on the route! I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thank you. It looks like I do have to make it into a shared module.